# Accumulated value problem - Find X using pthly annuity

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

A family wishes to accumulate 25,000 in a college education fund at the end
of 10 years. If they deposit 750 in the fund at the end of every six months for the first 5
years and 750 + X in the fund at the end of every six months for the second 5 years, find
X if the fund earns at effective interest rate 8%. (You must use the pthly annuity method
(ie. $\ a_{\overline {n}\rceil}$ or $\ s_{\overline {n} \rceil}$ to solve this question)

This is what I have come up with so far and I am not getting the correct answer ($X=237.72$ is the book's answer)
$25,000 = 750\ s_{\overline {5} \rceil}^{(2)} *(1+8\%)^5 + (750+x)\ s_{\overline {5} \rceil}^{(2)}$

Comment: perhaps it is a special term that I am not aware of. May I know what is pthly annuity method? what are $\ a_{\overline {n}\rceil}$ or $\ s_{\overline {n} \rceil}$

Comment: @Siong http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~jitse/math1510/notes-ch2.pdf answers both of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to transform the yearly interest rate $i$ into an equivalent semi-annual interest rate $i^{(2)}$.

$1+i=q=1.08\Rightarrow \sqrt{1+i}-1=\sqrt{1.08}-1=i^{(2)}$

And $(1+i^{(2)})^{m}=(1+i)^{m/2}$

Therefore the equation is

$$750\cdot 1.08^5\cdot \frac{1.08^5-1}{1.08^{0.5}-1}+(x+750)\cdot \frac{1.08^5-1}{1.08^{0.5}-1}=25,000$$

Comment: You´re welcome.